# Getting an error: non-whitespace before first tag Line 0 Column 1 Char:[ after installing Bluemix MQA plugin for my Cordova project

Tags: cordova, ibm-cloud

My Cordova project contains BMS Push plugin installed, and uses pods for dependencies. I installed the Bluemix Cordova MQA plugin and and when I tried to do a Cordova build, it threw the error `:- non-whitespace before first tag Line 0 Column 1 Char:[`

Cordova version used is 6.2.0, Xcode version is 8.3.1.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The MQA service has been retired by IBM:

https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/01/retirement-mobile-quality-assurance/

I recommend using Mobile Analytics or the Applause platform.

If you open up a support ticket through the official channel, the support team will be able to assist you until January 2018.